# Where does the word "masochism" come from, and how did it work its way into popular usage?

Tags: etymology

We all know that The Marquis de Sade popularized the term 'sadist' via "120 days of Sodom" and "Justine" - as well as being exemplified by his own devilish lifestyle. How/why was the word 'masochism' popularized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Masochism* is named after [Leopold von Sacher-Masoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_von_Sacher-Masoch), and you can get all of the filthy details at that link.

Comment: Yeah, well, I didn't use Google *or* Wikipedia. :)

Comment: @chaos, good for you! Would you like a gold star?

Comment: Well, I was hoping for *platinum*, but if gold is the best you can do, I suppose that would be all right.

Comment: But it's Tom Lehrer that captures the essence of it. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TytGOeiW0aE

Comment: @chaos - no need to beat yourself up about it ;-)

Comment: I think more interesting than the claim that masochism is filthy is the claim that it's unethical. The problem with words like "filthy" and "unsavoury" etc. is that someone can just pipe back "well, it's not filthy to me!" and they've won the argument, because it's all basically subjective anyway. Ethics, on the other hand, tends to be treated by human beings - myself included - as basically objective, irrespective of our philosophical preconceptions. In other words, it's easy to find people who don't really believe in the existence of morality per se, but it's much harder to find people...

Comment: ...who don't believe that those who have molested one or more children shouldn't be punished harshly for their gravely immoral actions. We're just wired to take morality seriously, and that means behaving as if it exists as an objective matter of fact. Ergo, to the extent that one can build arguments to the effect that masochism is unethical, this is inherently interesting, whereas the position that masochism is filthy is somehow inherently boring. Of course, this really has nothing to do with masochism per se, insofar as ...

Comment: ... we can replace masochism with any other set of actions that are arguably immoral, and the same point applies and is equally relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Uh, yeah, it's another eponym, by way of a dude named Masoch, sometimes praised as rather an *artiste* where de Sade is, by some accounts, fundamentally just a bully.

Comment: Might you be so kind as to elaborate

Comment: Elaboration is hardly necessary here. All hits on the first page of Google results for *Masoch* identify the dude in question. Doubtless all those pages will flag up the sexual proclivity, if you want to dig that deep.

Comment: Too bad no-one mentioned that his book : "Venus in Furs" is the direct method by which it was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Leopold von Sacher-Masoch wrote a book called "Venus in Furs" in 1870. A sadomasochistic relationship in which a masochistic man falls in love with a sadistic woman defines masochism and separates it from sadism.